# why after the 3rd click my function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<?php foreach ($this->tags as $uri=>$tag){?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $uri;?>" id="create_<?php echo $uri;?>" <?php echo isset($args['tags']) && in_array($uri, $args['tags'])?'checked="checked"':'';?> />
    <span onclick="selectTag(this.id)" id="create_<?php echo $uri;?>" for="create_<?php echo $uri;?>" class="tag <?php echo isset($args['tags']) && in_array($uri, $args['tags'])?'selected':'';?>"><?php echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $tag);?></span>
<?php }?>
```

And here is my JS code:

```
function selectTag(id) {
    var input = '.tags input#'+id;
    var span = '.tags span#'+id;
    if ($(input).is(':checked') && $(span).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(span).removeClass('selected');
        $(input).attr('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        $(span).addClass('selected');
        $(input).attr('checked', true);
    }
}
```

When I click on a span box, selects the box, and when I click again on it, it unselects it. The problem is, that after the 3rd time, it just stops working.

What is wrong with my code that is not working?

Comment: There is some error on your devtools console?

Comment: @FelipeKM, no, there is nothing

Comment: Have you tried using the JQuery prop method instead of attr?  Ex: $(input).prop("checked", true);

Comment: Your js looks fine, seems to be something on your php side, I just added the php tag to your question

Comment: @xDaevax WOW I can't believe that was that!! Thank you! Post your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery now has a prop method that is a slightly better alternative to using the attr method.

Try replacing your calls with `attr("checked", true);` with calls to `prop("checked", true);`

See here for documentation on prop: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Here for a discussion between the two: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

**Edit:**

Also, as Ed Cottrell stated, you'll want to have UNIQUE id attributes for all your elements on your page.

**Edit2:**

I have created a fiddle that demonstrates this usage: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/E39hc/

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the `input` and the `span` the same `id` attribute. Ids must be unique per element; you cannot have an `input` and a `span` the same `id`. Doing it this way will cause all sorts of problems, including the behavior you are experiencing.  Give one of them a slightly different `id` (like `create_<?php echo $uri;?>_span`).

Also, as @xDaevax says, you should use `.prop` rather than `.attr` -- I have had the same problem when using `.attr`.

Comment: Thank you!, I just noticed this. I changed it. Thanks a lot!